# grunt: run multiple task but with different configuration

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I could not think of an appropriate description for title, sorry. I am working on a project where the `Gruntfile.js` is already defined with certain task.

```
copy: {
   task1:{
   },
   task2:{
   }    
},
clean: ['folder']
grunt.registerTask('default',['clean','copy']);
```

I want to register another task that does clean and copy but in different folder/file and I want to run them only when I need some updates. Something like

```
copy:{
   newTask1:{
   }
}
clean:['newFolder']
grunt.registerTask('newUpdateTask',['clean','copy:newTask1']);
```

The problem is I don't want this new task in the original copy because when I run grunt default it will loop over the newTask as well which I dont want.